# google cloud datastore API update issue

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Following the guidance provided here (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions), I'm creating an entity with below schema

```
data: [
            {
                name: 'created',
                value: new Date().toJSON()
            },
            {
                name: 'name',
                value: templateObj.name,
                excludeFromIndexes: true
            }
        ]
```

I see this goes thru as expected and notice that the column "name" is not indexed.
[image]

Now, I use the transaction and update the entity. Below is the payload

```
[
  {
    "property": "active",
    "value": false
  },
  {
    "property":"name",
    "value":"new updated template"
  }
]
```

Code is exactly the same as documented.

While updating the data, why does it update the schema?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is really no schema when it comes to Cloud Datastore. It is schemaless. Any time you save (Insert or Update) an entity (regardless of its Kind), you have to specify whether or not the properties in the entity should be indexed. If you do not explicitly set the excludeFromIndexes, the property will be indexed. So, when you create an entity or update an existing entity, make sure to set the excludeFromIndexes to false if you want to keep the property unindexed.